# Uvicorn Detect --reload Main Thread

Tags: fastapi, uvicorn, pyngrok

I have a simple [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) application (built with [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)). In development, `uvicorn server:app --reload`. The `--reload` paramter means two threads will be started, one with the server, one to monitor file changes—when a file change is detected, the thread with the server is restarted.

Nothing special thus far. This is common in Flask, Django, and other dev servers as well. The catch is, I want to open a tunnel using `pyngrok` when I start the dev server, and I want that tunnel to be as long lived as the parent of these two threads. That is to say, when a file change is detected and the dev server is restarted, I do *not* want the tunnel to be restarted (since with `ngrok` this would cause a new public URL to be generated and break existing connections).

With Flask and Django this is relatively easy to accomplish. For example, with Flask I simply do `os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") != "true"`, with Django I similarly evaluate the `RUN_MAIN` environment variable, and in either case I only instantiate the tunnel when this these are set to `true`. I can't find a similar variable to use with Uvicorn. Can anyone help out here?

Comment: hey @alexdlaird did you find anything?

Comment: Nope. I've tried a few workarounds that I was going to leave here an answer for others to find, however, none of them have solved the problem either to my satisfaction either.

Comment: This is exactly what I've run into recently. Still no solution I suppose? @alexdlaird

Answer (score 0):

In FastAPI applications running with Uvicorn, you can check if the `--reload` option is enabled by examining the `sys.argv` list. The `sys.argv` list contains the command-line arguments passed to the script, and when the `--reload` option is used, it will be present in the list.

You can use the following code to determine if the `--reload` option is enabled:

```
import sys

def is_reload_enabled():
    return "--reload" in sys.argv

if is_reload_enabled():
    # Do not instantiate the tunnel when --reload is enabled
    print("Reload is enabled. Tunnel should not be started.")
else:
    # Instantiate the tunnel when --reload is not enabled
    print("Reload is disabled. Start the tunnel here.")
```